# Mysql Script in Go using exec.Command

Tags: mysql, go, terminal

I am trying to execute MySQL query which gives me the output as CSV file to the specified directory.

```
func executeCommand(){
    cmd := exec.Command("/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql", "-e", "-hlocalhost", "-P3131", "-uroot", "-pmyPassword", "dbName",  "> /path/to/output/folder/fileName.csv")
    var out bytes.Buffer
    var stderr bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &out
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr
    err = cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprint(err) + ": " + stderr.String())
    }
    fmt.Println("Result: " + out.String())
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> exit status 1: mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line
>   interface can be insecure.

When I removed the output directory path then there is no error.
But I need my output generated file to the specified directory.

I also tried replacing `>` with `source` but no luck.
Also, when I'm running the same on Terminal it is working as intended but I am failing to replicate the same through Go.

> /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -e "select * from tableName" -u root -p -h localhost -P 3131 dbName > /path/to/output/folder/fileName.csv

I tried searching on SO but couldn't find anything relevant.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Whosoever has downvoted my question, please have the courtesy to write the reason for the same. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41037870/go-exec-command-run-command-which-contains-pipe

Answer (score 3):

The `>` is a shell metacharacter for output redirection. When you run a command in the shell, the shell pre-parses your command and does special things with input/output redirection. It does not pass the redirection metacharacters to the program. But when you use `exec.Command()`, you only give the arguments you want to pass to the command.

If you want to save the output of the command, you need to work with your `cmd.Stdout` buffer.

See also [How to execute Mysql Script in golang using exec.Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894765/how-to-execute-mysql-script-in-golang-using-exec-command/46895115#46895115)

Comment: I saw your answer, but I just wanted to know, what should I write in place of '<'; source? Because using source I couldn't achieve the result as I'm stuck with the same error. And thanks for such an informative explanation.

Comment: You need to write code to write to the command's standard input and read from its standard output. Refer to https://golang.org/src/os/exec/example_test.go for examples.

Comment: I worked with my cmd.Stdout buffer and save that buffer into the file. Earlier I was stuck with exec.Command thinking it will directly output it to the file. Thanks for clearing this out.